# Message is consoling twice in the console - ReeactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Following is my very simple app which is increment the count from 10 to 11 in componentDidMount life cycle but in console 10 & 11 are appearing twice. I am interested to know why it is consoling twice.

Code -

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: 10
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        count: prevState.count + 1
      };
    });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.count);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div
          style={{
            width: "100px",
            height: "100px",
            background: "#efdef3",
            color: "black"
          }}
        >
          Count is {this.state.count}
        </div>
        <h3>Hello Frwo</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Output -

```
10

10

11

11
```

CodeSandbox Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-elbakyan-yszki

Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: uhu, curious. It render once, before `componentDidMount` ( with 10 ), and another after the state is updated ( with 11 ), that's the usual behaviour. But if you wrap your application with `React.StrictMode` you get your behaviour instead. Not sure way tho

Comment: nvm, https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074

Comment: @Federkun thx a lot for the comment...it works..please add your comment as an answer and I will accept yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard behaviour is that it render once, before componentDidMount ( with 10 ), and another after the state is updated ( with 11 ).

But on strict mode there's an additional re-render, only in development mode:

> It's an intentional feature of the StrictMode. This only happens in development, and helps find accidental side effects put into the render phase. We only do this for components with Hooks because those are more likely to accidentally have side effects in the wrong place.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074

Comment: what is strict mode in react?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are placing it with React strict mode.
This is an intentional feature:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using strict mode. This only happens in development mode, not your production build. More info on this here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects